# 7'' touchscreen - window manager

Tags: raspbian, xorg

I have bought a 7'' touchscreen. I would like to use fingers to display my graphs/camera picture/forecast maps. The way more The default window manager is ok with mouse, but not very effective with fingers.

Is there some touch-dedicated window manager? On Ubuntu, I know there exists a tiling manager XMonad, that could be more useful for touchscreens.

Do you advice other ways to use the power of the touchscreen, different than a dedicated application with large buttons?

Webpages displayed in firefox?

Comment: `apt search xmonad` tells me it is available on Raspbian if you want it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea how to use it. I tried on ubuntu, I can open windows that are nicely stacked - but I open from another terminal in another xsession...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From RPi's website:

> You can use the touchscreen interface of the display to operate your Raspberry Pi if you like, although the desktop is not designed to be used with touch devices. However, with the power of Kivy, you can make your own applications in Python that utilise the multi-touch features of the display. Watch this video for more information.

Kivy isn't an OS, but it could be useful for you.

Also, it's pretty hard to use an OS without a keyboard, you'd need a virtual one.

If you want a touchscreen for specific things, try Kivy or the tkinter library on Python.

Comment: Kivy looks very nice. I did not know about. It is a solution of one particular programming language though.  I dont suppose that 7'' display I have can do multitouch...does it?

Comment: The official Raspberry Pi 7" screen has 10 finger multitouch.